# Node.js app continuously consume memory without freeing it

Tags: node.js, http, memory-leaks, https, garbage-collection

I'm facing a weird situation. I wrote an application that is performing a HTTP GET request every five minutes. Something like this:

```
// pingy

'use strict';

var https   = require('https'),
    url     = require('url');

exports.ping = function ping (callback) {
    var options = url.parse('https://host.tld/ping');

    callback = callback || function () {};

    https.get(options, function handler (response) {
        var body = '';

        response
            .on('readable', function onReadable() {
                body = body + response.read();
            })
            .on('end', function onEnd() {
                return callback(null, body);
            })
            .on('error', function onError (err) {
                return callback(err);
            });
    });
};

// in other module
var pingy = require('./lib/pingy');

setInterval(pingy.ping, 300000);
```

Pretty straightforward. The thing is that after some time, the "rss" from process.memoryUsage() climbs and climbs. Looks like that the created ClientRequest objects will never be GCed(). Although I'm using https here in this example, the same happens if using the *http module*.

Do you have any idea what is wrong here?

**EDIT**:

I've solved the problem above (see below in my comment). Now I'm facing a different problem, which is really, really hard to track down (used [node-webkit-agent](https://github.com/c4milo/node-webkit-agent) in order to analyze the memory usage, but nothing really special. The heap looks stable to me). The scenario is also nothing special I'm copying round about 200 images from source to dest via Streams (see code below). What happens is, that the "RSS" increases also. I'm pretty sure that there is something wrong with my code regarding how to pipe the files. Don't get me wrong I have no problem with a high memory usage. With what I have a problem is, that the memory never will be freed. In order to verify that the memory will be cleared in some point in the future, I start a `http.createServer` after every single file has been copied. Even after a couple of hours the "rss" value stays the same.

So, well, again, do you have any idea what is wrong here? Thanks in advance for every hint! :)

```
'use strict';

var http = require('http'),
    fs   = require('fs'),
    path = require('path'),
    util = require('util'),
    directory = '/path/to/your/files/',
    jobs = [];

function printMemoryUsage () {
    var memory = process.memoryUsage();

    memory.rss = (memory.rss / 1024) | 0;
    memory.heapTotal = (memory.heapTotal / 1024) | 0;
    memory.heapUsed = (memory.heapUsed / 1024) | 0;

    console.log(JSON.stringify(memory));
}

function pipeFile() {
    var infile = jobs.pop(),
        outfile = jobs.pop(),
        instream = fs.createReadStream(infile),
        outstream = fs.createWriteStream(outfile);

    instream.pipe(outstream);

    instream.on('close', outstream.end.bind(outstream));
    outstream.on('finish', function onFinish () {
        // console.log('Finished %s -> %s', infile, outfile);

        instream.destroy();
        outstream.destroy();

        next();
    });
}

function next() {
    if (jobs.length) {
        setTimeout(pipeFile, 2000);
    } else {
        http.createServer(function (req, res) {
            res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
            res.end('Fooboot\n');
        }).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
    }
}

fs.readdir(directory, function (err, files) {
    files.forEach(function onIteration (file) {
        jobs.push(path.join(__dirname, file)); // outfile
        jobs.push(path.join(directory, file)); // infile
    });
    next();
});

setInterval(printMemoryUsage, 3000);
```

These are the memory footprints:

```
{"rss":13904,"heapTotal":6963,"heapUsed":1758}
{"rss":16012,"heapTotal":6963,"heapUsed":2016}
{"rss":26040,"heapTotal":6963,"heapUsed":2265}
{"rss":31468,"heapTotal":6963,"heapUsed":2453}
{"rss":41080,"heapTotal":6963,"heapUsed":2712}
{"rss":46620,"heapTotal":6963,"heapUsed":2844}
{"rss":49260,"heapTotal":6963,"heapUsed":1999}
{"rss":49524,"heapTotal":6963,"heapUsed":2249}
{"rss":49524,"heapTotal":6963,"heapUsed":2362}
{"rss":49788,"heapTotal":6963,"heapUsed":2621}
{"rss":49788,"heapTotal":6963,"heapUsed":2755}
{"rss":52692,"heapTotal":6963,"heapUsed":2001}
{"rss":52692,"heapTotal":6963,"heapUsed":2138}
{"rss":52692,"heapTotal":6963,"heapUsed":2270}
{"rss":52692,"heapTotal":6963,"heapUsed":2483}
{"rss":52692,"heapTotal":6963,"heapUsed":2600}
{"rss":52692,"heapTotal":6963,"heapUsed":2796}
{"rss":52956,"heapTotal":6963,"heapUsed":1951}
{"rss":52956,"heapTotal":6963,"heapUsed":2079}
{"rss":52956,"heapTotal":6963,"heapUsed":2343}
{"rss":52956,"heapTotal":6963,"heapUsed":2462}
{"rss":52956,"heapTotal":6963,"heapUsed":2689}
{"rss":52956,"heapTotal":6963,"heapUsed":2831}
{"rss":53136,"heapTotal":9011,"heapUsed":1927}
{"rss":53136,"heapTotal":9011,"heapUsed":2176}
{"rss":53136,"heapTotal":9011,"heapUsed":2273}
{"rss":53136,"heapTotal":9011,"heapUsed":2447}
{"rss":53136,"heapTotal":9011,"heapUsed":2545}
{"rss":53136,"heapTotal":9011,"heapUsed":2627}
{"rss":53136,"heapTotal":9011,"heapUsed":2804}
{"rss":53136,"heapTotal":9011,"heapUsed":2890}
{"rss":59732,"heapTotal":9011,"heapUsed":3100}
{"rss":65012,"heapTotal":9011,"heapUsed":3211}
{"rss":73496,"heapTotal":9011,"heapUsed":3409}
{"rss":79304,"heapTotal":9011,"heapUsed":3536}
{"rss":83792,"heapTotal":9011,"heapUsed":3633}
{"rss":95408,"heapTotal":9011,"heapUsed":3865}
{"rss":98840,"heapTotal":9011,"heapUsed":1824}
{"rss":98840,"heapTotal":9011,"heapUsed":2003}
{"rss":98840,"heapTotal":9011,"heapUsed":2205}
{"rss":98840,"heapTotal":9011,"heapUsed":2297}
{"rss":98840,"heapTotal":9011,"heapUsed":2491}
{"rss":98840,"heapTotal":9011,"heapUsed":2608}
{"rss":98840,"heapTotal":9011,"heapUsed":2717}
{"rss":98840,"heapTotal":9011,"heapUsed":2919}
{"rss":99368,"heapTotal":9011,"heapUsed":3036}
{"rss":99368,"heapTotal":9011,"heapUsed":3247}
{"rss":99632,"heapTotal":9011,"heapUsed":3351}
{"rss":99632,"heapTotal":9011,"heapUsed":3452}
{"rss":99896,"heapTotal":9011,"heapUsed":3606}
{"rss":99896,"heapTotal":9011,"heapUsed":3686}
{"rss":105968,"heapTotal":9011,"heapUsed":3824}
{"rss":106760,"heapTotal":9011,"heapUsed":1936}
{"rss":106760,"heapTotal":9011,"heapUsed":2022}
{"rss":106760,"heapTotal":9011,"heapUsed":2187}
{"rss":106760,"heapTotal":9011,"heapUsed":2279}
{"rss":106760,"heapTotal":9011,"heapUsed":2474}
{"rss":106760,"heapTotal":9011,"heapUsed":2614}
{"rss":106760,"heapTotal":9011,"heapUsed":2690}
{"rss":106760,"heapTotal":9011,"heapUsed":2854}
{"rss":106760,"heapTotal":9011,"heapUsed":2953}
{"rss":106760,"heapTotal":9011,"heapUsed":3241}
{"rss":106760,"heapTotal":9011,"heapUsed":3391}
{"rss":106760,"heapTotal":9011,"heapUsed":3535}
{"rss":107288,"heapTotal":9011,"heapUsed":3797}
{"rss":108248,"heapTotal":9011,"heapUsed":1908}
```

Comment: Is that the whole code? It doesn't seem to do anything with retrieved data.

Comment: Oh, right. I updated the code. The response body will be passed to the callback, but I don't need it in the interval. So for this scenario it is the whole code.

Comment: What is the memory usage over time. Give the details. GC begins to work once it reaches certain size. If it has not collected, it does not mean it will never happen.

Comment: After some further investigations over the last couple days, you were right user568109 - I also decreased the timeout on the server side, which is also a node application. Anyway, I've encountered another problem, which is hard to track down. I've already tried to analyze this with different profiling tools (see EDIT section).